# TFS API, How can i get "Assigned To" users for certain group ("In Group")

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

At Present i'm able to get all the users in TFS for AssignedTo Field by fallowing code:

```
var tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer("http://vstspioneer:8080/tfs/VSTSDF");
var workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var allowedValues = workItemStore.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo].AllowedValues;

foreach (String value in allowedValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

But my requirement is to fetch **only the users** who belongs to certain group("**In Group**").

I know that we can make use of FilteredAllowedValues with an filter. But my question is what to add in the filter if we want to fetch only certain group members.

```
var filters = new FieldFilterList();
  filters.Add(new FieldFilter(workItemStore.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo], ????));

var allowedValues = workItemStore.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo].FilteredAllowedValues(filters);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get all application groups with [IIdentityManagementService.ListApplicationGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.client.iidentitymanagementservice.listapplicationgroups(v=vs.120).aspx) Method first :

```
var sec = tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
Identity[] appGroups = sec.ListApplicationGroups(teamProject.ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Then you can get all members with in the Application Groups with [IIdentityManagementService.ReadIdentities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff738489(v=vs.120).aspx) Method.

This blog provides more details, you can check it: http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/30/tfs-sdk-get-groups-users-permissions-using-tfs-api-with.aspx